# SQL Access Add record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table/query in Access and would like to add new records, based on the date and number of months.

The idea is to add the following months of a record.

For example in my table I have the value 5 for June and it should be valid for 3 months, therefore I would like to add one line for July and one line for August with the value 5.

Existing table

```
Strg     NbMonths       Value      Date    
Abc      3              5          6/1/2017 
Abc      3              8          12/1/2017 
Rtg      1              2          7/10/2017
```

I would like to have

```
Strg     NbMonths       Value      Date 
Abc      3              5          6/1/2017
Abc      3              5          7/1/2017
Abc      3              5          8/1/2017
Abc      3              8          12/1/2017
Abc      3              8          1/1/2018
Abc      3              8          2/1/2018
Rtg      1              2          7/10/2017
```

I am using SQL in Access 2010.
Is-it possible to do it in an SQL query?

Comment: What is the PK in your table? and what did you try so far? why you can't just add it?

Answer (score 0):

MS Access lacks most of the obvious ways of doing this.  Here is an explicit way using `union all`:

```
select t.strg, t.nbMonths, t.value, t.date
from t
union all
select t.strg, t.nbMonths, t.value, dateadd(m, 1, t.date)
from t
where t.nbMonths >= 2
union all
select t.strg, t.nbMonths, t.value, dateadd(m, 2, t.date)
from t
where t.nbMonths >= 3
union all
select t.strg, t.nbMonths, t.value, dateadd(m, 3, t.date)
from t
where t.nbMonths >= 4;
```

You need a separate subquery for each value you want to expand to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *Cartesian* query for this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    T.Strg,
    T.NbMonths,
    T.Value,
    DateAdd("m", Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) , T.[Date]) As [Date]
FROM 
    TableStrg As T,
    MSysObjects AS Uno
WHERE 
    Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) < T.NbMonths
```

Output:

```
Strg NbMonths Value Date
Abc  3        5     2017-06-01
Abc  3        5     2017-07-01
Abc  3        5     2017-08-01
Abc  3        8     2017-12-01
Abc  3        8     2018-01-01
Abc  3        8     2018-02-01
Rtg  1        2     2017-07-10
```

Comment: Good idea but why *MSysObjects*?

Comment: @Parfait: Because it is always there! So the query will work right away. You may not like that, and some don't, even though MSysObjects has been there since V1.0 and will remain. If so, you can skip the modulus stuff and substitute with a simple table with one field holding sequential numbers from 0 to something.